# Hiding code in presentations programmatically

Tags: notebooks, code

A number of discussions is dedicated to hiding the code/input in presentations or notebooks. It is very simple to hide the input by hand.

I could not find, if it is possible to hide input by the code in this input cell, something like this

```
DoSomething;
HideCurrentInputCode;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
HideCurrentInputCode := (
    SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Previous, Cell];
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken[EvaluationNotebook[], "OpenCloseGroup"]];
)
```

Comment: This works! Thank you